# how to use Jenkins parameter in Ant's build.xml file

Tags: ant, jenkins

I want Ant to replace a token in a file with the build number from Jenkins.

I have a project that contains build.xml file with several tasks including:

```
<replace file="${web.dir}\index.html" token="@build@" value="${build_num}"/>
```

the "value" should somehow be resolved to the build number in Jenkins.

I 
In Jenkins, in build configureation -> ant -> advanced i set the following under properties:
first: build_num=$build , second: build_num=${build}

Neither worked , "$build" or "${build}" just appeared as the value instead of the token.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks,
N

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It's funny, I saw in some examples that people use ${build} for the build number, and I use it myself successfully in other places in Jenkins, but in this case it only worked with ${BUILD_NUMBER}.

Answer (score 1):

${BUILD_NUMBER} instead of ${BUILD} solved it